# Do I need to complete the intial setup of the Raspberry Pi in order to access it remotely?

Tags: remote, setup

I just got my Rasberry Pi and since I dont have any spare monitors, I want to know if its possible to set it up remotely (like installing the OS). I have seen some video showing how to use it remotely but they had the intial setup completed. So I was wondering if thats possible in my case as well and if so would the procedure be the same or different?

Thanks..

(Sorry if its a noob question... this is my first Raspberry Pi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to install Raspbian with a [headless](https://hackernoon.com/raspberry-pi-headless-install-462ccabd75d0) setup. That link will walk you through it, the main thing is to have SSH enabled which has been set as a default to disabled recently.

> (Sorry if its a noob question... this is my first Raspberry Pi)

You could almost say this was a... [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-noobs/) question. Ba dum tsh.

Comment: In the link above, it says to enable SSH by placing a file named 'ssh' ... is it just an empty file? Thanks

Comment: Correct. "For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named ssh, without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card. When the Pi boots, it looks for the  ssh file. If it is found, SSH is enabled, and the file is deleted. The content of the file does not matter: it could contain text, or nothing at all." [Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/)

Comment: ok just one more thing before I try this out... Do I connect the ethernet cable to the PC or the ethernet port on my wall or just straight into the router? Thanks.... (Good pun btw)

Comment: The Ethernet will go from your internet source to the raspberry pi. Most house hold setups are Wall -> Modem -> Router -> Devices. So I'm going to assume you will go Ethernet from Router to Pi.